# Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormat

Tags: java, jcreator

```
//FormattingOutput.java
/*This program shows how integer, String and floating-point variables can be formatted*/

public class FormattingOutput{
    public static void main(String args[]){

             String module1Name = "Mathmatics", 
                    module2Name = "Structured to Programming",
                    module3Name = "Web Design";
               
        int module1Students = 64, module2Students = 84, module3Students = 62;
        
        float module1Mark = 72.031f, module2Mark = 61.845f, 
                 module3Mark = 72.774f;
        
        String formatString = String.format("%-35s%-10d.lf\n%-35s%-10d.lf\n%-35%-10d.lf",
        module1Name,module1Students,module1Mark,module2Name,module2Students,module2Mark,
        module3Name,module3Students,module3Mark);
        
        System.out.println("Module Name    #Students  Average Mark\n" +formatString);          
    } 
}
```

Message:

```
--------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
```

I've no idea what I mistook
when I build up my code, there was no problem
after that,I complied but that message was showed
could you help me?

Comment: You have 9 values being printed, but only 6 format specifiers in the format string.

Comment: You're missing the format specifiers for the `moduleNMark` variables.

Comment: They should be after `%-10d`, where you currently have `.lf`.

Comment: The three `.lf` in the format should be `%.1f` (`l` (letter L) != `1` (digit one)), and you're missing an `s` on the third `%-35`.

Answer (score 0):

Java is parsing the String below format.

```
final String formatSpecifier = "%(\\d+\\$)?([-#+ 0,(\\<]*)?(\\d+)?(\\.\\d+)?([tT])?([a-zA-Z%])";
```

So your String.format should be

```
String formatString = String.format("%-35s%-10d.%1f\n%-35s%-10d.%1f\n%-35s%-10d.%1f", module1Name, module1Students,
                    module1Mark, module2Name, module2Students, module2Mark, module3Name,module3Students,module3Mark);
System.out.println("Module Name    #Students  Average Mark\n" + formatString);
```